# Why do emails from SourceForge mailing lists have the sender in reply-to (rather than the list)

Tags: sourceforge

I'm on a SourceForge mailing list, and when I get an email from the list it is shown as From whoever authored the email.  If I reply to that email, it appears that my email client (outlook.com) is going to send a message only to that sender.

Isn't that a bit contrary to the point of a mailing list?

I surmise that using "reply all" will cause the mailing list (which is in the to: field) to receive a copy, but that means the author whose message I'm replying to will get two copies of my reply?

I've looked for some explanation of how this is supposed to work, but can't really find anything.  Email lists I've been on in the past (at least the ones I've actively participated in) simply show the list as the sender, so a simple reply is a reply to the list.

Answer (score 2):

That's a configuration setting for the mailing list software and will have been a decision from the people who manage the list. You'll need to contact them to find out why they didn't go with a more traditional mailing list setup.